# Book and study recommendations - discrete geomtry

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

I am a Computer Science graduate student and my research topic (if you can call it that, since I just started) is discrete geometry. Stuff like Helly's theorem, convex geometry, p-q theorems, epsilon-nets etc.

I know some basics in that area, I have read a few papers and read some chapters about these subjects in books, but I don't feel like I'm understanding things well enough to be able to eventually come up with a topic I want to research.

I've taken linear algebra and analysis courses before, as well as a graph theory course all at math undergraduate level and some other courses like probability which weren't math undergrad level but were adjusted for CS students.

I feel like what I am missing is experience with the subjects that I've mentioned, I have read some books but solved little to no exercises related to these subjects.
I'm looking for a recommendation on how to approach combinatorial/discrete geometry (as it deals with higher dimension analysis most of the time and is different from the kind of math I'm used to) and a good handbook or online class that I can use to get better intuition and feel more comfortable dealing with these topics.

Thanks.

Comment: A rather high level book, covering only a part of what you want is "Geometric Combinatorics", by Rekha B. Thomas, AMS bookstore, Vol. 33, 2006